# Operator overload inside ruby block

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, block

I have this issue where I can't use an overloaded operator inside a block, instead of using the overloaded operator, it used ruby default operator and returns:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of String with 25 failed
```

The use case would allow the class to be used as:

```
Query.where { age > 25 }
```

As a notice, never mind the `method_missing` method below, it this context, it only serves the purpose of throwing the error message mentioned above, here's the code looks like:

```
class Query
  class << self
    def > arg
      "> #{arg.to_s}"
    end
    def method_missing meth, *args, &block
      "#{meth.to_s} #{args.first.to_s}"
    end
    def where &block
      "SELECT * FROM table WHERE #{class_eval &block}"
    end
  end
end
```

The overloaded operator runs fine if I add `self` inside the block:

```
Query.where { age self > 25 }
=> "SELECT * FROM table WHERE age > 25"
```

Take out the `self`, it returns this error:

```
Query.where { age > 25 }
=> ArgumentError: comparison of String with 25 failed
```

Comment: It looks like `age` is a `String`, not a `Query`. It's impossible to say more without seeing the definition of `age`.

Comment: A small simplification might help readers understand the problem: `def where; "SELECT * FROM table WHERE #{class_eval {age Query > 25}}"; end` and `Query where`.  It works with `Query` (`self`) present, but raises the exception you mention when `Query` is omitted.

Comment: `age` is handled by `method_missing`, if I were to define method `age` like the implementation of `method_missing`, a different error thrown, `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`, which confuses even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing meth, *args, &block
  "#{meth.to_s} #{args.first.to_s}"
end
```

returns a string when `age` is called. That means that your block:

```
{ age > 25 }
```

looks like this:

```
{ 'age' > 25 }
```

after `method_missing` has been called to handle the `age` call. There's your `ArgumentError`.

You need your `method_missing` to return something that knows how to respond to `>` in the way you need **and** that stringifies properly. For example:

```
class Query
  class Wrapper
    def initialize str
      @str = str
    end
    def > arg
      @str += "> #{arg.to_s}"
    end
    def to_s
      @str
    end
  end
  class << self
    def method_missing meth, *args, &block
      Wrapper.new("#{meth.to_s} #{args.first.to_s}")
    end
    def where &block
      "SELECT * FROM table WHERE #{class_eval &block}"
    end
  end
end
```

That will make `Query.where { age > 25 }` behave the way you want it to. That still leaves you with a unchainable string when you call `where` (i.e. things like `Query.where { age > 25 }.where { pancakes < 11 }` won't work) but extending `Query` to cover such things should be easier now that things are in the right places.

Comment: Did you mean `> 25` is passed as an argument to `method_missing`? I assume `> 25` to be called first, which should returns `"> 25"` then passed to `method_missing`, since I tested `Query.where { age height 25 }` returns `"… age height 25"`.

Comment: Not quite. `method_missing` is called to figure out what `age` means, then your `method_missing` was returning a string `>(25)` would be called on that string. That's why you kept getting errors about "can't compare String and Fixnum". If you add parentheses and explicit method-calling dots then it ends up looking like `age().>(25)` as far as the parser is concerned.

Comment: That's why I keep getting errors, but why isn't it evaluated like this: `age(>(25))`, is it because `>` needs two operand (the caller `age` and the argument `25`) and can't stand on it's own like `> 25`?

Comment: Ruby needs to know what object you're calling the `>` method on and the operator notation means that it has to call `age.>(25)` (not `age(>(25))`). `age.>(25)` means that Ruby needs to figure out what `age` is and since there isn't an `age` variable around, it sees it as `self.age` and that ends up as `self.method_missing('age')`; so the whole thing is `self.method_missing('age').>(25)`. `self.method_missing('age')` returns a string so everything falls apart in a pile of confusing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
Query.where { age self > 25 }
```

the object `self` is a `Query` Object, so it uses the operator you defined.
however, in this case:

```
Query.where { age > 25 }
```

neither `age` nor `25` are `Query` objects, so it's not going to use the operator from `Query`

Answer (score 0):

This is what's happening with `Query.where {age self > 25}`:

```
   class_eval {age self > 25}           
=> class_eval {age Query > 25}
=> class_eval {age Query.>(25)}
=> class_eval {age "> #{25.to_s}"}
=> class_eval {age "> 25"}
=> method_missing(age, ["> 25"])
=> "#{age.to_s} #{["> 25"].first.to_s}"
=> "age > 25"
```

With `Query.where {age > 25}` we have:

```
class_eval {age > 25}
```

which raises an error because `age` is assumed to be the receiver of `v`.

You could change `Query.where { age > 25 }` to `Query.where { age "> 25" }` and delete your `'Query#>'` method. You may not need some of the `to_s`'s.